# Computer does not boot with P4000 and NVIDIA drivers

Tags: boot, nvidia, intel, 18.10

I have a new Dell PC with an NVIDIA Quadro P4000 graphics card. I installed Ubuntu 18.10 on it. After the default installation, it works fine.

However, I need the NVIDIA drivers. I have installed versions 390 (from the Ubuntu software updates tool), and versions 410 and 418 from NVIDIA's PPA site. All present the following problem: booting fails, immediately after Grub's menu, with a purple screen. The machine is not responsive, and I cannot get to a terminal.

Following the advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1122743/932376), I added `nomodeset` to Grub's kernel parameters. When I do that, the machine boots, I can run benchmarks, `nvidia-settings` runs, and things seem to be fine.

However, I suspect that's just a stopgap hiding a deeper problem. I have read many answers and followed their advice (for example [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087050/932376)) without any success.

The computer also has an integrated Intel display, and my suspicion at the moment is that there's a conflict between Intel and NVIDIA when modeset is enabled. However, I don't know how to start testing that hypothesis.

Any advice would be appreciated. Here's a little bit more data about the machine; I can provide more details if needed. The BIOS is dated 11/01/2018. Secure boot has been disabled the whole time.

```
$ sudo lshw -short  # I have removed many irrelevant lines
H/W path        Device      Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         OptiPlex 7060 (085A)
/0/0                        memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/9                        memory         32GiB System Memory
/0/14                       memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/15                       memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/16                       memory         12MiB L3 cache
/0/17                       processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
/0/100                      bridge         8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/1                    bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Con
/0/100/1/0                  display        GP104GL [Quadro P4000]
/0/100/1/0.1                multimedia     GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/2                    display        Intel Corporation
/0/100/8                    generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Process

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.18.0-16-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-022) (gcc version 8.2.0 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1)) #17-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 8 00:00:57 UTC 2019
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot and remove nomodeset.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this piece of information: secure boot has been disabled the whole time. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've been able to find is to add

```
i915.modeset=0
```

to Grub's kernel parameters. This allows the Nvidia card to use modesetting. Also, this seems to confirm my suspicion that the problem was the interaction between two active video cards: the built-in Intel and Nvidia's.